# Transform Monthly Costs to the cost on daily basis for some particular month

Tags: mysql, sql, psql

I have a table with raw data like:

```
campaign costs   start_date end_date
brand    132.25  2019-04-01 2019-04-30
brand    155.25  2019-05-01 2019-05-31
```

Costs are the sum on monthly basis per some marketing campaign. What i need to do is to count them on daily basis (Costs/(End_date-start_date)
and have a view where i see the costs on daily basis.

```
campaign costs   Date
brand   4.40    2019-04-01
brand   4.40    2019-04-02
brand   4.40    2019-04-03
brand   4.40    2019-04-04
brand   4.40    2019-04-05....
```

Would be thankful for any help.

Comment: What database are you using?  MySQL and psql are very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres, you would simply do:

```
select t.campaign,
       t.costs / (t.end_date - t.start_date + 1),
       gs.dte
from t cross join
     generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') gs(dte);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c4b8c6941ccc84da85f983f8f9740d26) is a db<>fiddle.

Note this produces a fractional amount for the costs.  If you want 4.40:

```
round(t.costs / (t.end_date - t.start_date + 1) - 0.005, 2),
```

Comment: @dmitriypetrychukmiete . . . `gs` is a table alias for `generate_series()`.  `dte` is the name of the column that it produces.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8 onwards:

```
with DATES as
(
select campaign, start_date as thedate
from Mytable
union all
select campaign, date_add(start_date, interval 1 day) 
from DATES
where thedate < end_date
)
select t1.*, costs/datediff(end_date, start_date) as newcosts
from DATES t1
left join MyTable t2
on t2.campaign = t1.campaign
and thedate between start_date and end_date
```

Pre MySQL 8:

Populate a numbers table from 0 to 30:

```
create table Numbers (NN integer);

Insert into Numbers (NN) values (1),(2),...,(30);
```

Now use it:

```
select t1.*, t2.costs/datediff(t2.end_date, t2.start_date) as newcosts
from
(
select campaign, date_add(start_date, Interval NN day) as Thedate
from MyTable 
cross join Numbers
where date_add(start_date, Interval NN day) <= end_date
) t1
left join MyTable t2
on t1.TheDate between t2.start_date and t2.end_date
```